# Java - Sort Alphabetically as well as collate unique elements together

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a array list filled with objects which each have info about them.
For Example :

```
{Term(C,2), Term(H,2), Term(C,1), Term(O,3)}
```

The goal right now is to change the arraylist so the result is something such as this :

```
{Term(C,3), Term(H,2), Term(O,3)}
```

We want to collate the like terms together. I have the following at this stage.

```
char element = 'A';
int amt_atom = 0;
int index = 0;

char alphabet = 'A';
char alpha = 'A';

for (; alpha <= 'Z' ; alpha++){
    search:
    for ( ; alphabet <= 'Z' ; alphabet++ ) {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < terms.size() ; i++){
            if ( terms.get(i).getElement() == alphabet){
                element = terms.get(i).getElement();
                amt_atom = terms.get(i).getAtoms();
                index = i;


                System.out.println(element + " , " + amt_atom + " , " + index );
                alphabet++;
                break search;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < terms.size() ; i++){
        if ( terms.get(i).getElement() == element && i != index){
            int amt_atoms2 = terms.get(i).getAtoms();
            terms.set(index, new Term ( element, amt_atom + amt_atoms2 ));
            terms.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the array given might not be alphabetic and we must also put it in alphabetic order. 
Another example would be: `CH3CH2CH2CH2CH2CH3` and the result = `C6H14`.

Edit : Sorry, should have specified what was wrong with the original code.
So, Doing `C2H2HO3` results in `C2H3O3`which is fantastic because its right but when i try `CH3CH2CH2CH2CH2CH3` then i get `C2H5` which is not at all correct. I am not sure why that is .

Am I even on the right track? Could someone maybe tell me what i am doing wrong?
I am fairly new to Java and therefore have an extremely basic knowledge so it would be good if you can explain something while using structures and elements of java that i might have used above. Thanks

Comment: What is wrong w/ the code you currently have?

Comment: @ScottHunter Good Point. Sorry, Should have specified. Edited :)

Answer (score 3):

How about first sort, then collate? You could make your `Term`'s implement the `Comparable` interface and then just call `terms.sort();`. Then go over the list and collate, which is easier once it's sorted.

Don't worry too much about performance here. It should be fast.

Comment: To tell you the truth, i have the most basic knowledge of Java possible at this stage so basically have no idea what you said about the `Comparable` interface. But i will now have a look and will see if i can do something. :)

Comment: Ah. Sorry. In that case check up on interfaces in general and how to make your class an instance of an interface, then look into the `Comparable` interface. Once you have that down, sorting will be the easiest thing ever.

Comment: Thanks, Gonna go ahead on that. :) Do you have any idea what's actually wrong with my code?

Comment: To be honest I did not look that closely. I just saw that you seem to want to solve both problems at the same time, and that you seem to be sorting manually so I had a spontaneous suggestion right away =)

Comment: Alright. Cool. That's fine. If you have time then i would love to get some feedback on what the actual issue with the code i have right now might be and if there are any general things i can do to improve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy do with Java 8:

```
//grouping by alphabet
Map<Character, List<Integer>> groupedTerms = terms.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Term::getElement)))
//Calculate count
Map<Character, Int> calculated = groupedTerms.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()));
//And sort
Map<Character, Int> result = calculated.stream().sorted(Map.Entry.byKeyComparator()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

As result you have sorted map Character - Int:

```
["A"-> 10, "C" -> 5]
```